# Structure of Spin(Q)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory

I would like to understand better the structure of the algebraic groups called $\text{Spin}(Q)$, where $Q$ is a quadratic form defined over a field $K$. I know that such a group is a double cover of $\text{SO}(Q)$, but I have not seen a "concrete" description (whatever that may mean) of the map $\text{Spin}(Q) \to \text{SO}(Q)$, and not of $\text{Spin}(Q)$ itself. In particular I would like to understand these groups better when the ground field $K$ is a $p$-adic field, but I have not managed to find good references. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Any book on spinors describes it explicitly as a subgroup of the multiplicative group of the Clifford algebra. I am voting to close.

Comment: Look at Volume 2 of the Collected Works of Claude Chevalley, The Algebraic Theory of Clifford Algebras and Spinors.  He works over an arbitrary field (even characteristic 2!) and the book is exceptionally clearly written.

Answer (score 2):

One common way to understand this is via [Clifford algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra#Spin_and_Pin_groups). Namely, $\operatorname{Spin}(Q)$ can be explicitly described as a subgroup of the Clifford group, and there is a natural map from the Clifford group to $O(Q)$ whose restriction to $\operatorname{Spin}(Q)$ lands in $SO(Q)$. This map is the standard double cover. The Wikipedia page contains the necessary details.

Comment: This can also be found in N. Bourbaki, Elements of Mathematics. Algebra, Part I: Chapters 1–3, Hermann, Paris, 1974.